# Log-log transformations exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm self-studying a [book on statistics by Andrew Gelman](https://avehtari.github.io/ROS-Examples/) and I'm having trouble with this exercise. I hope someone can help me here.

Suppose that, for a certain population of animals, we can predict log weight from log height as follows:

- An animal that is $50$ centimeters tall is predicted to weigh $10$ kg.
- Every increase of $1\%$ in height corresponds to a predicted increase of $2\%$ in weight.
- The weights of approximately $95\%$ of the animals fall within a factor of $1.1$ of predicted values.

a) Give the equation of the regression line and the residual standard deviation of the regression

b) Suppose the standard deviation of log weights is $20\%$ in this population. What, then, is the $R^2$ of the regression model described here?

I'm having trouble figuring out how to derive the coefficients of the regression line. I have some ideas but I'd rather hear some experts out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since you have some, could tell what are your ideas first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regression equation would be
\begin{equation}
\log(w) = 2 \log(h) + (\log(10)-2\log(50)) \quad \Rightarrow  \quad \log(w) = 2 \log(h) - 5.5
\end{equation}
where weight $w$ is in kg and height $h$ is in cm.

95% of weights fall within a factor of 1.1 of predicted weights, and $\log(1.1) = 0.095$ (equivalent to two standard deviations), so residual standard deviation would be 0.048.

Finally to calculate $R^2$, you simply apply

\begin{equation}
R^2 = 1-\frac{\mathrm{SE}_\mathrm{line}}{\mathrm{SE}_\mathrm{y}} = 1-\frac{0.048}{0.2} = 0.76
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm unsure of how you arrived at -90 as intercept. I do like this: $ \beta_0 = log(w)-(0.02/0.01)*log(h) = -5.5$

Comment: Or solve for a, $ln(10) = a + 2*(ln(50))$,
a = -5.5

Comment: @PaulCrebs Oh that's because since you wrote log-transformed, I took it as 50 centimeters log-height is predicted to log-weigh 10 kg. But your interpretation is more natural.

Comment: how do you go from factor 1.1 to 2 standard deviations?

Comment: @PaulCrebs I think I made a mistake, corrected the factor and also $R^2$.

Comment: Oh yes. Now it makes sense. Hey man, thanks a million for taking the time to help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: ... But I must admit: I still don't understand which formula you use to derive at 0.048 from factor 1.1. I've been reading through the chapter and I'm still unsure of this.

Comment: @PaulCrebs [This](https://quantifyinghealth.com/residual-standard-deviation-error/) might help you.